# What's the grammar of "rescued" in "may the Heaven rescued land"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjunctives, lyrics

"The Star-Spangled Banner" the 4th stanza

> O thus be it ever, when freemen shall stand
>   Between their loved homes and the war's desolation.
>   Blest with vict'ry and peace, **may the Heav'n *rescued* land**
>   Praise the Power that hath made and preserved us a nation!
>   Then conquer we must, when our cause it is just,
>   And this be our motto: 'In God is our trust.'
>   And the star-spangled banner in triumph shall wave
>   O'er the land of the free and the home of the brave!

Why is the verb "rescue" in the ed-form? (simple past or past participle?)

Why not "may sb do sth", like "may God *bless* you"?

---

By the way, "the land" is shortened to "land" for the sake of rhythm, no?

---

Edit: 1 I mistook "Blest with vict'ry and peace, may the Heav'n rescued land 
/ Praise the Power that hath made and preserved us a nation! " as two separate sentences, just because it is divided into two lines.

2 If there were a hyphen between "Heaven" and "land", I would have viewed "the Heaven-rescued land" as a whole. The text in Wikipedia doesn't have.

Comment: It's *May the Heaven-rescued land (blessed with victory and peace) praise the Power that has made and preserved us as a nation!* Does that help?

Comment: By the way, no.  "Land" *has* a "the" here.  The noun phrase (in modern orthography) is "the Heaven-rescued land".  That's the subject of a clause which does use a "may somebody do something" pattern.  Much like "may God bless this land", this is "may this land praise God".

Comment: @userr2684291 You completely solved my problem, see my edit.

Answer (score 10):

> May a **flea-bitten dog** be your best friend.

A dog bitten by fleas.

> the Heav'n-rescued land

The land rescued by Heaven.

**rescued** is the past-participle there.